# Separate integers from a string and divide the integres by a constant. (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, split

I have a string

```js
let str = 'a12b-a24b';
```

And I'm replacing the alphabets and splitting the string into two parts

```js
let [result1, result2] = str.replace(/a/g,'').replace(/b/g,'').split('-');
```

I want to divide the numbers by a constant say 2 before assigning them to `result1` and `result2` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten the replace using a character class `[ab]`

Then split on a hyphen and map the value to an int if they are whole numbers and divide by 2.

```js
let str = 'a12b-a24b';
let [result1, result2] = str.replace(/[ab]/g, '')
  .split('-')
  .map(s => parseInt(s, 10) / 2);
console.log(result1)
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: What if `a` and `b` are special characters ?

Comment: @Kundan In that case you can replace all characters that are not either a digit or a hyphen using `[^\d-]` instead of `[ab]`

Comment: Let's assume my string is `$1k-$10k`. Then what I've to write to remove all `$` and `k`  ?

Comment: @Kundan You would write it like this `let str = '$1k-$10k';
    let [result1, result2] = str.replace(/[^\d-]/g, '')
        .split('-')
        .map(s => parseInt(s, 10) / 2);` See an example here https://ideone.com/vOF1Tw

Comment: But you have not mentioned the `k` there, why it still work ?

Comment: @Kundan You can either be specific about what you want to remove like for example `[abk$]` but you can also make the pattern broader using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[^\d-]` meaning match any other char than a digit or a hyphen. And that any other char will include also the `k`

Comment: Okay, thanks for your support. The answer really helped me. I hope you liked my question.